# Get List item viewID from popup window

Tags: list-view

I am using sharepoint 2010 List in which I am able to get the viewID of the list and while viewing an item it opens a poup window from the sharepoint list I need to get the viewID of that item can anyone give an solution to get the viewID of an item?

Comment: thanks for the post. Actually i need to catch up the popup window in share point 2010 list item. Can any one please help me to find out. Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

An Item doesn't have a View ID - only a list.

Why do you need the ViewID in the pop up window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've asked the right question. However, on the assumption that you really want the viewID, the following approach *might* work, so long as the viewID is in the url of the page that calls the dialog.

Use the **HttpRequest.UrlReferrer** property if you need the data server-side (or **document.referrer** if you need it client-side). This gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL and should be parseable to pull out the viewID.